# Accessing a Matrix field in a Global

Tags: matrix, globals, table-field

I have created a Global with the handle 'footer', which contains a Matrix field 'links' and I'm trying to get this into a template, but I can't seem to get this to work.

The 'links' Matrix contains a Block Type 'navigation' with a Plain Text field 'navigationHeadline' and a Table field 'navigationLinks'. The table field contains 'linkLabel' and 'linkUrl' columns (see attached image).

I'm ultimately creating my navigation in a Global with a Headline and some Links and the Headline should only appear if each block has some links;

```
{% for block in entry.links %}
    {% if entry.navigationLinks | length %}
        <h3>{{ block.navigationHeadline }}</h3>
        {# Show the navigationHeadline if it has links #}
        <ul>
            {% for row in entry.navigationLinks %}
                <li>{{ row.linkLabel }} - {{ row.linkUrl }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I wondered if anyone can help me resolve my obvious errors. Thanks.

[image: Screenshot of Global]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure why you're referencing "entry" in your code, I'd think the code should be:

```
{% for block in footer.links %}
  {% if block.navigationLinks | length %}
    <h3>{{ block.navigationHeadline }}</h3>
    {# Show the navigationHeadline if it has links #}
    <ul>
      {% for row in block.navigationLinks %}
        <li>{{ row.linkLabel }} - {{ row.linkUrl }}</li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

So, "links" is the matrix on your "footer" global, which you can access from anywhere. You loop over that, get a block for each matrix block, and access "navigationHeadline" and "navigationLinks" through that.